# Retrieving SharePoint view via a Url - Client Side Object Model

Tags: sharepoint, office365, csom

I'm having a bit of trouble finding how to retrieve data from view via the Client Side Object Model. I have the Url to the list view available, but I cannot seem to fetch data via this. I can retrieve the List, but that only returns the default view, not a specific one.

The View class has a property for ViewCollection.GetById, but that is asking for a Guid, which I'm also at a loss of getting via Url. Is this a possibility at all? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

By default you could retrieve [View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.view%28v=office.15%29.aspx) by:

- title: [ViewCollection.GetByTitle method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.viewcollection.getbytitle(v=office.15).aspx)
- `id`: [ViewCollection.GetById method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.viewcollection.getbyid(v=office.15).aspx)

**How to retrieve View by its Url**

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve View by Url:

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace SharePoint.Client.Utilities
{
    public static class ViewExtensions
    {
        public static View GetViewByUrl(this List list,string viewUrl)
        {
            var ctx = list.Context;
            var result = ctx.LoadQuery(list.Views.Where(v => v.ServerRelativeUrl == viewUrl));
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            return result.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var viewUrl = "/[site]/[web]/[list]/viewname.aspx";
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
   var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
   var view = list.GetViewByUrl(viewUrl);
   Console.WriteLine(view.Title);
}
```